# Problems With Emailing Through A Submit Button

Tags: php, html, email, submit-button

After going through my website the user can email me a file and a brief description to go along with it. However once the user of my website clicks the submit button, he goes to a page that says "this webpage is unavailable" and I don't get an email.

I have been using PHP and HTML for this part of my website and I don't know why it isn't working.

PHP

```
<?php
mail('Example@gmail.com', $_POST['Subject'], $_POST['Content']);
?>
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="email.php">
<input type="file">
<input type="text">
Content Goes Here
<br>
<br>
<input type="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like `libmail` class for sending Emails, in most cases it fixes the problem.
If even after making it work with `libmail` you will get an issues, try to use `SMTP` along with libmail.
Cheers.

Sure, here is example of usage:

Download php_libmail class with this link http://webi.ru/base/files/tovar/php_libmail_2_1.zip

Then use this code:

```
<?php
include "libmail.php"; // including the class
$m= new Mail; // create instance
$m->From( "asd@asd.com" ); // from
$m->To( "who@asad.com" ); // to
$m->Subject( "Subject zzz" ); // subject
$m->Body( "Hey, pal" ); // body
$m->Cc( "copy@asd.com"); // copy of email, if need
$m->Bcc( "bcopy@asd.com"); // hidden copy of email, if need
$m->Priority(3) ;    // priority of message, i think from 1 to 5
$m->Attach( "asd.gif","", "image/gif" ) ; // attachment, if need
$m->smtp_on( "smtp.asd.com", "login", "password" ) ; // via SMTP, if need
$m->Send();    // And the magic Send ;)

echo "Message body:<br><pre>", $m->Get(), "</pre>";
?>
```

For make functionality you need, just create simple HTML form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute and add any fields you want, files, inputs, texts, any of those.
And then in you PHP script accept those field values via global $_POST variable and pass accepted values into the libmail instance ;)
For accepted files use global $_FILES variable.

Comment: So how can the user of my website change the body and the attachment.

Comment: Well, this is your task to code such functionality ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [PHP Mailer](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wiki/ExamplesPage) for sending any mail.
It is very helpful and easy way to do this kind of work.

Code would be like-

```
<?php

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

//PHPMailer Object
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//From email address and name
$mail->From = "from@yourdomain.com";
$mail->FromName = "Full Name";

//To address and name
$mail->addAddress("recepient1@example.com", "Recepient Name");
$mail->addAddress("recepient1@example.com"); //Recipient name is optional

//Address to which recipient will reply
$mail->addReplyTo("reply@yourdomain.com", "Reply");

//CC and BCC
$mail->addCC("cc@example.com");
$mail->addBCC("bcc@example.com");

//Send HTML or Plain Text email
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
$mail->Body = "<i>Mail body in HTML</i>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else
{
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}
```

[Here](http://www.sitepoint.com/sending-emails-php-phpmailer/) is a illustrative example given for this.